# Why All topics are getting same id when subscribeHeaders is not passed in props to SockJsClient from "react-stomp" library

Tags: reactjs, stomp, sockjs, stompjs

This is the strange behaviour I encountered while subscribing to multiple topics with react-stomp library.

These are the topics passed:

```
0: "/topic/settings/update"
1: "/queue/9999999999/notifications"
```

```
<SockJsClient
        url={apiUrl}
        topics={this.props.topics}
        onMessage={this.onMessage}
        ref={(client) => { this.clientRef = client; }}
        debug
 />
```

(Notice that I didn't pass subscribeHeaders first)

I kept some breakpoints to debug in `react-stomp/dist/client.js` and `stompjs/lib/stomp.js` to see what ids get assigned to those subscriptions.

[image]
This (Above image) is the first call in `react-stomp/dist/client.js` for the first topic. we can see subscribeHeaders in this.props is nothing but a blank object.

[image]
This (Above image) is the first call of subscribe function in `stompjs/lib/stomp.js` and we get blank object as headers argument.

[image]
This (Above image) is the second call in `react-stomp/dist/client.js` for the second topic (**Notice that, this time we get subscribeHeaders out of nowhere**)

[image]
This (Above image) is the second call of subscribe fn in `stompjs/lib/stomp.js` for the second topic: (Now, we have headers in parameters so we the second "if" condition will be false **hence, giving the same id to te second topic also**)

**This whole strange problem can be solved by passing "subscribeHeaders={null}" and then each topic starts getting different ids (i.e. "sub-0", "sub-1")**

```
<SockJsClient
        url={apiUrl}
        subscribeHeader={null} //only works when passed "null". Doesn't work if passed blank object "{}"
        topics={this.props.topics}
        onMessage={this.onMessage}
        ref={(client) => { this.clientRef = client; }}
        debug
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is because the actual `subscribeHeaders` object is getting modified by the stomp.js.

Javascript passes Object to a function as a copy of the reference. This means that if the object is changed inside the function then the actual object also changes.

Because of the above Javascript behavior, the first call to subscribe is adding the `id` with `sub-0` which is changing the `subscribeHeaders` object, and then that object is getting passed to subsequent calls for subscribe.